# JavaScript HTTP request works with false for synchronous request but not true

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I made an API with ExpressJS and when I try a GET request with this:

`requestData.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/get-data", false)`

it works and gives me a depreciation error in the console but if I use

`requestData.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/get-data", true)`

it doesn't work. Is it ok to keep using false even with the warning?

Comment: Just don't use it?

Comment: It still doesn't work if I put nothing

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: Im console.logging the response and its blank if I don't put anything. Same if I put true.

Comment: `async` flag has been deprecated for 10 years now. Find a modern tutorial on AJAX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)